# When I Compare two variables using javascript it gave me Wrong result

Tags: javascript

```
var var1 = $("#<%=cmbDropdown1.clientID%>")[0].value);
var var2 = $("#<%=cmbDropdown2.clientID%>")[0].value);
if(var2 < var1) {
  alert("Works Fine");
} else {
  alert("Not FIne");
}
```

Now this code works fine when var1=7 and var=9 
but when var1=9 and var =10 than it give wrong output.
please Help me..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: That code should not run due to multiple syntax errors.

Comment: Instead of `$('#thing')[0].value` `$('#thing').val()` would be better. That way you're not mixing jQuery and vanilla JS unnecessarily.

Comment: You should use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function for converting string to integer.
If value contains floating point then use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Try this:

```
var var1 = parseInt($("#<%=cmbDropdown1.clientID%>")[0].value), 10);
var var2 = parseInt($("#<%=cmbDropdown2.clientID%>")[0].value), 10);

if(var2 < var1){
 alert("Works Fine");
} else{
  alert("Not Fine");
}
```

Comment: It should be `parseInt(bla, 10)` because otherwise you can get unexpected results if something looks like an octal number. Using unary plus is probably even better (`+bla`).